# functors and object inheritance

Tags: c++, stl, compiler-errors, functor

A brief outline:
I have a base class that builds some data objects.  I then have a child class that inherits all the public methods and pointers to objects from the base class.

In that child class, I want to construct a functor (as a struct) to use in a for_each loop.  My problem is that in the functor operator, I get an error when trying to access objects.

Abbreviated example:

```
class Child  : public BaseClass {
  Child(DataSource& in_data): Base(in_data){};

  struct foo {
    double operator() (int x){  
        double y = in_data.some_function(x);
        // do stuff
    }            
  };
}
```

> error: not able to access in_data.some_function.

Ideas?

Comment: Show the code for `DataSource`.

Comment: Is `in_data` a member of `foo`?

Comment: Long and complicated code.  Child can access and use data source functions without a problem.  It seems as if the functor doesn't get that inheritance.

Comment: We are not interested in the implementation (I assume that's what is long and complicated), but the definition.

Comment: You didn't tag C++0x but ... why not use a lambda?

Comment: @Emilio: because there is frequently no advantage and can be harder to work with? ... Also: because it is not tagged c++11 :)

Comment: @sehe: many times I agree, but ... let the OP to answer in this specific case!

A lambda is not that "harder" then define a class for that sole purpose. It's "hander" because it's a new feature we may not be yet accustomed to it. But it's just a matter of time.

Comment: @Emilio: Lambda's can be harder to work with because libraries don't support it as functions (look at boost::bind, phoenix::bind; they start supporting it through using the standard library `result_of` implementation, but think of the not-so-highly abstracted libraries - it will take a while!). Also, to let the OP decide, get off your soapbox ;)_

Answer (score 6):

*[Nested classes](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc/language/ref/cplr061.htm)* don't have visibility of members of their enclosing class (they're like `static` nested classes in Java).

If you want `foo` to access `in_data`, you will need to provide it a reference explicitly.  So in `foo`'s constructor, either have it take a reference to a `DataSource`, or a reference to a `Child` (and pass `*this`).

Comment: Edited to add a refernce to Nested classes documentation, Hope you won't mind that.

Answer (score 1):

Your `foo` doesn't know about `DataSource`.

consider this

```
struct foo
{
   DataSource& ds;
   foo(DataSource& a) :ds(a) {}

   double operator() (int x)
   {
     double y = ds.in_data.some_function(x);
     .....
   }
};
```

You have to create foo by giving it  a DataSource  to refer to.

Comment: Nice,  Can I just give it a pointer to the "child" function so that it has access to **all** of the objects in child?

Comment: @Noah: yes, of course. I just did the minimum to make your sample work.